# How to update parent component when child (third party) component state is changed

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am using third party RN component.
I use that component like:

```
<Component  ref={comp => (this.comp = comp)} ...
```

That component allow me to access data via:

```
this.comp.state.height
```

This component is part of my component and my problem is
I need to take some action when that third party component state is changed.
When it's state is updated my parent component can't detect that change.
How can I track this change (I can't change third party component)?

Comment: 14, which third party component are you using? Does it have any documented props like `onSomeValueUpdated`, so that when its internal value (that you're interested in tracking) changes, it calls `this.props.onSomeValueUpdated`?

Comment: I am using this component: https://github.com/archriss/react-native-display-html

Answer (score 0):

One of [that component's props](https://github.com/archriss/react-native-display-html#props) is `onMessage`, which is of type function.

Assuming that is the change you want to track, you may do something like:

```
<Component
  ref={comp => (this.comp = comp)}
  onMessage={this.onMessage.bind(this)}
  ...
```

And then inside your custom component's class from which you're rendering that 3rd-party one, include this function:

```
onMessage(data) {
  // data here is what was sent from window.WebViewBridge.send
}
```

Comment: Yes I saw that but from some reason onMessage is never called. That is why I asked if somehow I can detect it's state change as this.comp.state.height is updated just this onMessage is never called.

Comment: `react-native-display-html` has its own [internal `onMessage` function](https://github.com/archriss/react-native-display-html/blob/master/index.js#L152) that gets called when the underlying `WebViewBridge` component calls its `onBridgeMessage` prop. What if you add `console.warn(JSON.stringify(event, null, 2))` inside `onMessage` as the first line? That way, you can determine if `react-native-display-html` that has a bug or the `react-native-webview-bridge` it uses.

Comment: It looks like the `onMessage` function right there (not underlying webview-bridge) is erroneous, because inside `if (height) { ... }` it never calls `onMessage(eventData)`

Comment: If you're using `console.log`, do you have your react-native simulator or device running with Debug JS Remotely option enabled? Because if not you'll never see the log output. Just want to make sure.

Comment: Yes debugger is on